# Indexing with mongodb: bad performance / indexOnly=false

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongodb on a 8GB linux machine running. Currently it's in test-mode so there are very few other requests coming in if any at all.

I have a colelction items with 1 million documents in it. I am creating an index on the fields: PeerGroup and CategoryIds (which is an array of 3-6 elements which will yield in an multi key): `db.items.ensureIndex({PeerGroup:1, CategoryIds:1}`.

When I am querying

```
db.items.find({"CategoryIds" : new BinData(3,"xqScEqwPiEOjQg7tzs6PHA=="), "PeerGroup" : "anonymous"}).explain()
```

I have the following results:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor PeerGroup_1_CategoryIds_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 203944,
    "nscannedObjects" : 203944,
    "nscanned" : 203944,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 203944,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 203944,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 680,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "PeerGroup" : [
                    [
                            "anonymous",
                            "anonymous"
                    ]
            ],
            "CategoryIds" : [
                    [
                            BinData(3,"BXzpwVQozECLaPkJy26t6Q=="),
                            BinData(3,"BXzpwVQozECLaPkJy26t6Q==")
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "db02:27017"
```

}

I think 680ms is not that very fast. Or is this acceptable? 
Also, why does it say "indexOnly:false" ?

Comment: Hmmmm... the high number of nscanned seems to indicate that it first searches by one of the arguments and then searches by the other in the result set. Is 203944 rather the number of documents with PeerGroup:anonymous or of BinData(3,"xqScEqwPiEOjQg7tzs6PHA==")?

Comment: Maybe it's because PeerGroup is an array and with db.items.ensureIndex({PeerGroup:1} you are only finding results when you are searching for a certain combination of CategoryIDs?

Comment: Forget about my last post. The documentation clearly says "Creating an index on an array element indexes results in the database indexing each element of the array"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think 680ms is not that very fast. Or is this acceptable?

That kind of depends on how big these objects are and whether this was a first run.  Assuming the whole data set (including the index) you are returning fits into memory, then they next time you run this it will be an in-memory query and will then return basically as fast as possible.  The nscanned is high meaning that this query is not very selective, are most records going to have an "anonymous" value in PeerGroup?  If so, and the CategoryId is more selective then you might try an index on `{CategoryIds:1, PeerGroup:1}` instead (use [hint()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint) to try out one versus the other).

> Also, why does it say "indexOnly:false"

This simply indicates that all the fields you wish to return are not in the index, the `BtreeCursor` indicates that the index was used for the query (a BasicCursor would mean it had not).  For this to be an `indexOnly` query, you would need to be returning only the two fields in the index (that is: `{_id : 0, PeerGroup:1, CategoryIds:1}`) in your [projection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields).  That would mean that it would never have to touch the data itself and could return everything you need from the index alone.

Comment: Ah. PeerGroup contains only three different values which are uniformly distributed, ie. 1/3 1/3 1/3 = 1. Actually I return only one field that is a reference to another collection-id but which is not included in the index since it is never queried. Would it make sense to add this field to the index to make the query faster?

Comment: Btw: 680ms is not for the first run. Using a limit on the find basically makes the query very fast -> 0ms. But the count still takes some time

Comment: I am guessing that it's a combo of the low selectivity (lots of results) and the scan and load that is slowing it down then - you may get a boost by adding the third field since that will mean it won't have to load the data too, just the index (don't forget to explicitly not return _id or it will still be indexOnly false).  The  trade off is that the index will be bigger, of course, but there will be a lot less data in RAM.

Comment: DOn't know if that would speed things up, because Count is nearly as fast/slow as Find. Is there any way to explain() a Count?

Comment: No, but assuming you are not CPU bound, the count won't be adding much to the find.  If you are not seeing page faults during the find, and the index changes are not helping (and you are getting an indexOnly true), then without a schema change I'm not sure it's going to get faster

Comment: I am assuming that adding the field to the index to get an indexOnly true won't help anything with the count, does it?

Comment: It will mean that the document itself will not need to be loaded into memory to do the count, instead it will execute on the index alone.

Comment: well but why does count need to load the document into memory? for counting only the query itself is relevant not the options on the cursor, i.e. returning all the fields? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You said you were counting based on another field that was not in the index (first comment), if it is not in the index, and you are counting it, then it will have to be loaded from the document

Comment: no, sorry. that's a misunderstanding. the query does not include the the field i am returning thus I am not counting nor finding on that field. i am doing teh following: query = {"CategoryIds" : new BinData(3,"xqScEqwPiEOjQg7tzs6PHA=="), "PeerGroup" : "anonymous"}. db.items.count(query); db.items.find(query, {_id:0, ProductId:1})

Comment: Aadd a projection to the first query to not return _id, and only return the fields you are counting so that it can use the index only.  The second query, the find, would benefit from an index on ProdustId, assuming you don't already have one.